# Save ParseObject (subclass) to cloud => [success], pin it immediately => [success], get objects from pinned group [0 results]?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a very simple subclass of ParseObject - `Wallet`. I am creating one new instance and saving it to the cloud via `saveEventuall()` and immediately afterwards trying to pin it to localstore (and eventually broadcast a signal to my app so it can update UIs since it reads objects only from the localstore for perfrormance.

Here's how I register the subclass in Application.onCreate():

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Wallet.class); // <----

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
    Parse.initialize(this, "private stuff", "private stuff");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null)
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().signUpInBackground();
}
```

Here is the full subclass itself:

```
@ParseClassName("Wallet")
public class Wallet extends ParseObject {

    public Wallet() {
    }

    public void putName(String name) {
        put("name", name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return getString("name");
    }

    public static ParseQuery<Wallet> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Wallet.class);
    }
}
```

And then a simple save of an object to the cloud, pin it locally and trying to retrieve it from the pin for testing:

```
            final Wallet c = new Wallet();
            c.putName(name);

            c.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) e.printStackTrace();

                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), c.getObjectId() + " is the saved object id");

                    c.pinInBackground("wallet", new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e != null) e.printStackTrace();

                            ParseQuery<Wallet> pq = Wallet.getQuery();
                            pq.fromPin("wallet");
                            pq.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(int i, ParseException e) {
                                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), i + " items in pin after saving one");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

And to my surprise, here's what I see in LogCat:

```
06-29 11:29:00.279: D/(3480): J6ljTKezMf is the saved object id
06-29 11:29:00.303: D/(3480): 0 items in pin after saving one
```

What? I just got the item saved to cloud and then pinned it? How come there are 0 items inside the pin group?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Parse, `ParseObject` class names are case sensitive. In your code, you've got the line `pq.fromPin("wallet");`, but you have declared your class as `"Wallet"` so no results are being returned. Try changing `"wallet"` to `"Wallet"` in that line.

Comment: The parameter being passed to fromPin() is a pin group name. Not the name of the ParseObject(s) I am trying to retrieve. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Plus I just tested and the effect is the same. Even tried pininBackground() and fromPin() with no first parameter (just the callback as parameter) and the result is still 0 items pinned. The object is saved to the cloud though. I can retrieve it from cloud every time, but this renders my app useless for offline usage.